# Can't set cookies on localhost with domain name in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, cookies, sitecore

I have tried solutions from other posts about this issue, but I am still unable to get it to work.

I am just trying to add cookies to the response from the server. In a normal .Net MVC solution that runs on `localhost:<some port>` this works fine:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cartId", "3")
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12)
            });
```

I have an explicit domain like this: `127.0.0.1 SitecoreTestProject.com`

I have tried the following code from a Controller Action:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("hello", "world")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12)
        });
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("hello2", "world2")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12),
            Domain = "sitecoretestproject.com"
        });
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("hello3", "world3")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12),
            Domain = ".sitecoretestproject.com"
        });
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("hello4", "world4")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12),
            Domain = "localhost"
        });
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("hello5", "world5")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12),
            Domain = ".localhost"
        });
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("hello6", "world6")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12),
            Domain = null
        });
```

Any help is appreciated